# Finding the center of a circle drawn using leaflet draw and also calculating the distance between 2 latlong

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Am new to JS and the below queries may looks simple thing.

Query:
I have drawn multiple circles on the map and i need to fetch all the markers details available with in the circle.

In order to achieve that am trying to fetch the center of circle in lat long and calculating the distance of all markers on the map from that center of circle. 
if (distance <= radius) concluding the marker is with in the circle.

1. How center of the circle is determined.
2. how distance is calculated between the center and the marker ?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have something like that somewhere :

```
var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
```

and also that you added this options to your L.Control.Draw :

```
edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
    remove: false
}
```

as the L.Draw documentation says.

Now you can search your circles :

```
var circleList = [];
editableLayers.eachLayer( function (l) {
    if (l instanceof L.Circle) {
        circleList.push(l);
    }
});
```

Same way to search for the markers :

```
var markerList = [];
editableLayers.eachLayer( function (l) {
    if (l instanceof L.Marker) {
        markerList.push(l);
    }
});
```

Now you want any marker which is inside any circle :

```
var markersInside = [];
var i;
for (i=0; i<markerList.length; i++) {
    var j;
    var m = markerList[i];
    var mposition = m.getLatLng();
    for (j=0; j<circleList; j++) {
        var c = circleList[j];
        var cposition = c.getLatLng();
        var cradius = c.getRadius();
        if (cposition.distanceTo(mposition) <= cradius) {
            markersInside.push(m);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dafvwetz/) which artificially declares the featureGroup.

Do not hesitate to read [leaflet doc](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html) which contains pretty much everything i used and is very well written.

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for helping me. i had a doubt here, am trying to search the markers of icon type in the call back of L.Draw.Event.CREATED, when am trying to accessing the editableLayers it is showing only one layer which is of Circle type.

Note: ICON kind markers is added.